# C sockets, proxy GET requests returning as 404

Tags: c, sockets, proxy

I'm creating a simple proxy server and I've run into an issue with getting responses back from a website.

I've set up my server to accept connections on a specified port that gets connected to through the browser proxy config. The server is able to receive the request, connect to the specified website, send the request, and receive a reply.

I'm forwarding the request from the browser to the website without modification, but the replies I receive are always 404 errors.

This is the request I'm fowarding to the website, there is a \r\n after every line and \r\n\r\n after the final line.

```
GET http://www.mywebpage.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mywebpage.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=1.35811746.1525489860.1537250282.1539467023.3; __utmz=1.1537250282.2.2.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); _fbp=fb.1.1553849756364.1600689742
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

My send receive code looks like this.

```
sendError  = send(serverSock, requestString , strlen(requestString) , 0 );  
returnedSize = recv(serverSock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm forwarding the request from the browser to the website without modification
> ...
>
> ```
> GET http://www.mywebpage.com/ HTTP/1.1
> ```

The [absolute URL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2) you use in your [request target](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3) should only be used for proxies. Normal servers expect the [origin form](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1), i.e. only the path and optional query but not the full URL. Method, host and port should thus be stripped:

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
```